# How to force acceptance of site terms on first login?

Tags: terms, content-restriction

I want to force users to accept the terms and conditions of the site when they log in for the first time. I found a couple plugins that would show the terms, but they don't prevent you from ignoring the form and moving on to other site pages. Is there a way to prevent the user from going anywhere until they have accepted the terms?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a modal window the same way it's used on the [IBM website](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/rational-software-architect-family): a window without a close button. Without clicking on agree and proceed, the users will not be able to visit the website.

As for a Wordpress solution for that, if you use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) you can create your own model.

Answer (score 1):

For such a user always redicect him to his profile page (or whatever other page) until he agrees to the TOS. something like (expect syntax and other errors in the code)

```
add_action('init','wpse_2204693_force_tos');

function wpse_2204693_force_tos() {
   $user = get_current_user();
   if (get_user_meta($user->ID,'TOS',true) != 'done') {
     wp_redirect('profile url);
     die();
   }
}
```

in your TOS form you do `add_user_meta($user->ID,'TOS','done',true);` after the user had approved the TOS